Gcloud: Deploying flask app from git repo failing with DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 error when installing requirement.txt
I have built a flask app with python version 3.9, and kept it in a github repo. It successfully runs on render.com. To learn Google App Engine, I cloned the repo, moved into the folder and tried installed the packages using:pip install -r requirements.txt. Every time I run this command I am getting a long DEPRECATION error:

Initially, I didn't had app.yaml file. So I added it in the Gcloud shell:
runtime: python39

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app

env_variables:
  ENV: 'production'

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto

Still I'm getting the same error with pip install -r requirements.txt! What could the problem?

It worked with pip3 command!

Unless you have a specific requirement for App Engine, I'd encourage you to consider Cloud Run. App Engine was a remarkable technology but it's time has passed and Cloud Run is a modern technology platform that likely (!) provides you with more modern skills and better opportunities for employment (unless you're working with an existing App Engine customer).

On systems that support both Python 2.x and 3.x, pip is a Python 2.x command, and pip3 is a Python 3.x command. The same goes for python versus python3. Suggestion, as the message warned you, you should be using a Python virtual environment.
